# nm-applet disappeared from top panel Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, network-manager

I know there are many similar questions. None of those solutions have worked for me. If I try running nm-applet in terminal, this is the output I get...

** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to describe what you have already tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

that should reinstall nm-applet to the tray, you may have to reboot.